# Hooking up buttons to JavaScript function with MySQL entries

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I have a table in a database that I would like to render using XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript  to a PHP page. I want to render each entry in the table as a HTML row/cell and have two buttons in each "entry". I want to have every button in the entry call a particular JavaScript function that would process the logic.

So basically, if I have 10 rows in the table, I will have 20 buttons and each button will pass a parameter to either 2 functions depending on which "type" of button was clicked.

Any ideas on how I can go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your server, you need a PHP file/action doing something like:

```
$return = array();
$q = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ...');
while(($return[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) !== false);
echo json_encode($return);
```

In the pre-built HTML page, you'll need a container for the data to be printed:

```
<div id="db-container"></div>
```

Then the JS included in that page (I use jQuery here for simplicity and readability, though you can do it using native JS or probably any other JS tool):

```
function getDB() {
  $.getJSON(
    'http://url.to/your/code.php',
    {},
    function(data) {
      var renderedHTML = '';
      /* parse the object representing PHP's $return, mainKey will be numerical keys */
      for(var mainKey in data) {
        /* one main loop iteration == one table row */
        renderedHTML += '<tr>'
        /* data[mainKey] is a row in DB, subKey will contain a name of a DB table column */
        /* data[mainKey][subKey] will therefore contain the value of DB table column 'subKey' for the DB table row numbered 'mainKey' */
        for(var subKey in data[mainKey]) {
          renderedHTML += '<td>' + data[mainKey][subKey] + '</td>'
        }
        /* statically add another HTML table column for the buttons */
        renderedHTML += '
          <td>
            <input type="button" name="b1" onclick="func1(\'arg1\')">
            <input type="button" name="b2" onclick="func2(\'arg2\')">
          </td>
        ';
        renderedHTML += '</tr>'
      }
      /* insert the built table into the page */
      $('#db-container').html('<table>' + renderedHTML + '</table>');
    }
  );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I personally do not know jQuery but I understand your approach. I can probably do this in javascript. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! For translating jQuery to JS, `$.getJSON` is just a `XmlHttpRequest` with an expected return type `text/json`, though you can use the encoding you prefer; `$('#element').html(data)` is the same as `document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = data`. Be careful however as `innerHTML` is poorly implemented in most browsers, you may want to use it along with the safer DOM methods `createElement` and `appendChild` ([here is a link](http://domscripting.com/blog/display/99) describing the trick to force the DOM to be properly rebuilt when inserting a subtree into it). Good luck!